# My Javascript for-loop works on all but one sub-array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
  function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var lista = [];
    var max = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++){
        if (arr[x][y] > max) {
        max = arr[x][y];
        }
      lista[x] = max;
      }
    }
    return lista;
  }

 largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

^ generates the following array: [27,27,39,1001], but the answer is: [27,5,39,1001]

My function correctly shows the maximum number in each sub-array, EXCEPT the 2nd subarray. I don't understand what part of my code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You never reset the `max` variable. You need to reset it at on each iteration of the outer `for` loop. (If the sub array with `1001` had been the first sub array your result would've been `[1001, 1001, 1001, 1001]`.)

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var lista = [];
  var max;
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    max = 0;  // <-- add this line
    for (var y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++){
      if (arr[x][y] > max) {
        max = arr[x][y];
      }
    lista[x] = max;
    }
  }
  return lista;
}
    
console.log(largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Incidentally, you can implement the same thing with fewer lines of code if you do something like this:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(a) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math,a);
  });
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Or even shorter with arrow functions:

```js
var largestOfFour = arr => arr.map(a => Math.max.apply(Math,a));

console.log(largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can write this function in one line. You can apply `.map()` function on your array, and return the max element of each sub array by using `Math.max()` method.

```
function largest(array) {
  return array.map(a => Math.max(...a));
}

console.log(largest([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

You should take a look about functional programming, it can be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset max
Move its def inside the first loop